# Python script to take a column of IPs, search for matches in another workbook for matchs, place matches in another workbook.

Tags: python, vba, excel, openpyxl

I am working with Excel sheets for migration prepping. I have a workbook/sheet that has all network server IPs that exist on Netscalers (MAS). I need to take a column of IPs listed in my Migration_prep workbook/sheet and loop through the IPs in the MAS sheet and take any matches and place them into another workbook. 
I can do these with text documents but I would love to just keep all the data in excel sheets. I have read the book "Automate the Boring Stuff With Python" but it does not teach how to do this. I have searched on google and here for answers but nothing even comes close.

```
import openpyxl
import xlrd
import xlwt


wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('LB_migration.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('Servers')
#IP should be placed in Column 'J2' and continue down for as much as needd.

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('ME06.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('Dependency_Details')
#Migration server IPs are listed in Column P starting with row 2.

wb3 = openpyxl.load_workbook('MAS.xlsx')
ws3 = wb3.get_sheet_by_name('massheet')
#All servers listed in Netscaler configs are in column C starting in row 2
#This should be the list that is parsed with the Migration server IPs

ws1.iter_rows('A1:A235')
```

Comment: If you read the chapters on loop and openpyxl, you'll find it does in fact give you everything you need.

Comment: I read that chapter through twice and went out and got Python Crash Course for more detail on loops. Thank you

Comment: Please provide an example of a single comparison and change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to put the data into a python list for each of the columns you want to compare:

`mylist = []
for col in ws1.columns[0]:
    mylist.append(col.value)`

after reading the data in, you can just use more for loops to find the data you want via comparisons.

Comment: I was going to write a different answer but I think this covers it. Using loops and the `iter_rows()` function you should be able to get what you want.